# How to create continuous line boundary on the image?

Tags: image-processing, data-analysis, image-segmentation, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I just started working in the image processing field and got a problem. I hope somebody could suggest me the way to approach it.

Input: 1 image or a 3D stack of images.

[image: 1]

Output: The same image or a stack but with continuous white lines (boundaries).

Just for a broader perspective, the general task is to segment the image on black "grains" and white "boundaries".

The process of segmentation of similar pictures but with continuous boundaries is already working just fine.

Please let me know your thoughts on this. Any reference on algorithms, software or even theories are very welcome.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68150887/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you try [dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) with a proper kernel, your problem might be solved.

Comment: The attached image, how was is generated? That cannot be any original acquisition, some processing has already been applied. I recommend to take a step back and revisit that processing.